# React-Native Android - Invariant Violation: "TheApp" has not been registered

Tags: java, android, react-native

After I upgrade a major part of all my packages, when I run `react-native run-android`, I got this error :

```js
Invariant Violation: "TheApp" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is running from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it, and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.
```

I haven't had this problem with iOS, the app works fine.

After some research, I try some things.
React-Native `0.69` for both.

**MainApplication.java**

I modify these lines :

```js
...
@Override
protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
  return "src/index.mobile"; //this line
}
...
```

**MainActivity.java**

I modify these lines too :

```js
...
@Override
protected String getMainComponentName() {
  return "TheApp"; //change the name here
}
...
```

In the file **app.json**, I put the same name :

```js
{
  "name": "TheApp",
  "displayName": "TheApp"
}
```

Finally, in **index.mobile.js**, I do this :

```js
import './Business/Config/ReactotronConfig'
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native'
import App from './mobile/App/Containers/App'

AppRegistry.registerComponent("TheApp", () => App)
```

Everything work in iOS, but not in Android.
Don't know what to do.

Comment: did you end up finding a solution to this? I am having a similar problem..

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and this worked for me.

I discovered that my old app was installed in my android emulator.  This fixed it for me:

1. I uninstalled both the app and the new app from the emulator.
2. I killed both Metro and the emulator.
3. I restarted both Metro and the emulator.

It turns out the emulator retains each app it installs instead of starting out as a blank slate each time as I expected. When it starts up, it tries to load the app with the earliest install time. So, it kept trying to run my old app and contact the old Metro server instead of running my new app.